# How to use a Java List as the values of a Hql Insert?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, firebird

I'm building a project with Hibernate 4.0, Java 8.

The goal of the project is to sync two database. 
Postgresql and Firebird.

I have a method called insertIntoFirebird() that get the values from Postgresql Table
and insert them into the Firebird table.

```
public void insertIntoFirebid(){
    sessionPostgresql.beginTransaction();
    sessionFirebird.beginTransaction();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Profissional> profissional = sessionPostgresql.createQuery("SELECT P.NOME, P.CPF, P.RG, P.EMAIL, P.ENDERECO, P.UF from Profissional P Order by P.ID").list();

    sessionPostgresql.close();

    Query insert = sessionFirebird.createSQLQuery("insert into Conta values(profissional)");

    sessionFirebird.update(insert);

    sessionFirebird.close();
}
```

How can I use the values of profissional list as the values of the hql insert ?

Comment: Offtopic, why you need to use hiberante to sync db, rather use us spring-batch(Though you can use Hibernate to read/write the data to ). I would have gone to your approach if there was an need to write on to other db on an hibernate event  listener

Comment: I actually need to write in the other DB.

Comment: You could iterate over your result list and save your professional by calling `sessionFirebird.save()` inside of transaction.

also take a look here [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html)

Comment: Gonna try this buddy, Thanks for the help. If it works I'll tell you. :)

Comment: Put your comment as an answer, because it worked :). I wanna approve your answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over your result list and save professional by calling `sessionFirebird.save()` inside of transaction. Also take a look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html)